# Custom UINavigationBar works on simulator but not on released version

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, testflight

I'm hoping to get some insight into an issue I've been struggling to wrap my head around for the past few hours.  I have a custom UINavigationBar that is being configured in `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` by calling the following method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

When I run my application in XCode (both in the Simulator and on an actual device that is plugged in to the computer), this works great and my custom background is displayed. However, when I run a release version of the app on TestFlight, the standard light blue navigation bar is showing. After messing with placement of the `setBackgroundImage` method with no luck, I have come to believe it has to do with differences in "debug" vs. "release" settings, but I am clueless as to where those settings would cause this navigationBar issue.

Any help or insight into this issue (or how I would go about debugging it) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably issue with different iOS versions?

Comment: @ACB, both the simulator and beta versions were running iOS 6.0+

Comment: Then check the spelling of `NavBar` image name added to project. Is it `navBar` or something like that? Because it will work in simulator but not in device in that case.

Comment: Wow, yes it is titled "navBar". As a follow-up, why would that work in the Simulator but not on the actual device?

Comment: Yes it is case sensitive. Looks like someone tried putting the same after I commented.

Comment: @ScottLieberman The simulator's file system is (normally) case insensitive (depends on whether your Mac's filesystem is case sensitive or not - and it is not by default). An iOS device's file system is always case sensitive. Just one of the many subtle, but critical, difference between the simulator and a real device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, when you are facing similar issue you should check the name of images and make sure it is not case sensitive. You might have added an image with name `navBar` but you are using as `NavBar` in your project. That is the reason for this issue. Simulator is not case sensitive but device is.

Either change the code to,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the device image names are treated as case sensitive. Also you need to supply it with extension.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.**png**"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

So check exact name and extension.

Comment: Extension is not required and it should be navBar not NavBar. That was the reason for issue.